# La connexion entre Notre-Dame et la prière « Je Vous salue, Marie »

Tags: culture

C'est une question culturelle. J’espère qu’elle est permise.

J’ai vu que plusieurs Parisiens chantaient la prière « Je Vous salue, Marie » dans différents lieux pendant que la cathédrale Notre-Dame de Paris brûlait, lundi dernier.

Quelle est la connexion entre Notre-Dame et cette prière ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about french language

Comment: [Obligatory musical setting by Brassens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wvlz1_TOYHk)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Les églises catholiques sont généralement dédiées à des Saints (par exemple, Saint Pierre à Rome). C'est aussi le cas avec Marie (la mère de Jésus), que l'on appelle également Notre-Dame (surtout chez les catholiques), Sainte Marie, Mère de Dieu, Sainte Vierge, Immaculée Conception ou Vierge Marie.

Notre-Dame et Marie étant la même personne, la prière était directement adressée à "Notre-Dame".

Comment: Pas ***ou** à Marie* mais ***dont** Marie*, Marie étant une sainte (Sainte Marie). Les églises catholiques sont quasiment toutes dédiées à un saint ou une sainte. Il arrive aussi qu'elles soient dédiées à plusieurs saints, en particulier Saint Pierre et Saint Paul. Quelques églises ne sont cependant pas dédiées à des saints (Église de l'Annonciation, Église Sainte-Croix, Église de la Sainte-Trinité, etc.)

Comment: merci pour ces précisions, j'ai adapté ma réponse.